# smtp relay - gmail - swiftmailer: Expected response code 220 but got code ""

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, swiftmailer

I am using gmail as an smtp server for my swiftmailer class.

however I am getting

> Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message "" in "\classes\Swift\Transport\AbstractSmtpTransport.php"

What does this mean?

Comment: Found out what It was, Gmail requires SSL encryption.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it probably means you sent a blank line to the smtp server.

Make sure none of your commands have line feeds in them.

Can you log the transaction and paste a copy of the log?

see here for details about logging
http://swiftmailer.org/docs/logger-plugin

Answer (score 0):

I got this when I had the wrong setting in the factories.yml file as below.

`class: Swift_SendmailTransport`

But it should be the following.

`class: Swift_SmtpTransport`

Answer (score 0):

For users of **smtp-relay.gmail.com**, if you use localhost/127.0.0.1 as domain during developments, you probably need to change the domain name to use in `EHLO` command to begin the transaction.

For SwiftMailer Symfony bundle (since 2.4.0), you can set the [`local_domain` config parameter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#local-domain):

```yaml
// config/packages/dev/swiftmailer.yaml
swiftmailer:
    ...
    local_domain: dev.mydomain.tld
```