# Laravel 4: Password::remind(...): Expected response code 220 but got code "250"

Tags: php, smtp, laravel, laravel-4, swiftmailer

When I run this:

```
public function postForgot()
{
    $credentials = array('email' => Input::get('email'));
    return Password::remind($credentials);
}
```

I get:

```
Expected response code 220 but got code "250", with message "250 OK "
```

But the code I run comes from the documentation. What am I doing wrong?

I've searched for SMTP response codes and 250 seems to be the response code for a succesful message transfer. Could this be a bug that SwiftMailer is comparing to the wrong response code? (probably not)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the remind() method look like in your Password class?

Comment: @RobW http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Auth.Reminders.PasswordBroker.html#68-95

Comment: Oops, duh. The code is coming from swift mailer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940698/smtp-relay-gmail-swiftmailer-expected-response-code-220-but-got-code looks related - if you're using Gmail's smtp, enable SSL.

Comment: SSL already enabled, for php right? @RobW

Comment: No, for the SMTP connection... applies if you're using Gmail as your SMTP server.