# Symfony2 SwiftMailer sendmail transport error

Tags: php, forms, symfony, swiftmailer

I wish implementer a contact form on my website.
i followed the symfony2 documentation : http://symfony.com/fr/doc/current/cookbook/email/email.html

i use symfony 2.3.3.

So that is my config_dev.yml:

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: sendmail
```

My contactAction controller:

```
 public function contactAction(Request $request)
    {
        $this->focus = "contact";

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder()
            ->add('Sujet:', 'text')
            ->add('Service:', 'choice',
                array(
                    'choices' =>
                        array(
                            'all' => 'Communication multi-canaux (plusieurs services liés)',
                            'web' => 'Développement Web',
                            'webMarketing' => 'Web Marketing',
                            'mobile' => 'Développement mobile / tablette',
                            'brand' => 'Brand design',
                            'event' => 'Evènementiel',
                            'print' => 'Campagne print',
                        ),

                    'preferred_choices' => array('all'),
                )
            )
            ->add('Nom:', 'text')
            ->add('Societe:', 'text')
            ->add('Courriel:', 'email')
            ->add('message:', 'textarea')
            ->getForm();

        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            // Les données sont un tableau avec les clés "name", "email", et "message"
            $data = $form->getData();
            $message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
                ->setSubject($data['Sujet'] . $data['Société'])
                ->setFrom($data['Courriel'])
                ->setTo('contact@visual-immersion.com')
                ->setBody($this->renderView('text à placer par la suite'))
            ;
            $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
        }

        $this->get('mailer')->send($message);
        return $this->render('VisualImmersionSiteBundle:Site:contact.html.twig',
            array(
                'focus' => $this->focus,
                'form'   => $form->createView(),
            ));
    }
```

i have this error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 2 passed to
>   Swift_Transport_SendmailTransport::__construct() must implement
>   interface Swift_Events_EventDispatcher, instance of
>   Swift_Transport_StreamBuffer given, called in
>   /var/www/visual-immersion/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php
>   on line 2129 and defined in
>   /var/www/visual-immersion/vendor/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Transport/SendmailTransport.php
>   line 42

and I absolutely can not find where the problem is. Do you have any ideas, or have you experienced this error?

Thank you for your help

UPDATE:

i downgraded SwiftMailer package to 2.3.2 version in composer. The problem was solved, but now, i have this error message;

> Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""

any idea ?

Comment: Looks to me like the swiftmailer library issue is resolved now, but I guess you still have some configuration issues with your server if `sendmail` and `mail` transports are either raising errors or not sending emails. response code `220` is service ready... so it's not really. pity there's no actual response code! can you tell me more about the environment you are using?

Comment: I found an [intriguing SO answer - might be worth a look? It suggesting that blank lines might be the issue - I have no idea, but you can use the Symfony web profiler to view the format of the mail you sent. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940698/smtp-relay-gmail-swiftmailer-expected-response-code-220-but-got-code/4941051#4941051

Comment: alternatively if you are having ongoing issues with your environment, have a look at using SMTP via gmail or even Mandrill, the latter of which is a transactional email service (from MailChimp) that gives you 13,000 free mails a month.

Comment: @Darragh my dev env is ubuntu server 13.04 with php 5.4.9. I tried gmail transport, but i have "Cannot send message without a sender address
500 Internal Server Error - Swift_TransportException" error.

Comment: Maybe my setTo is false ? in don't know...

Comment: Possibly. This is sort of turning into a different issue that your original question - but in order to enforce valid input perhaps you could add validation to enforce the mandatory fields in your form. You can read **Validating Values and Arrays** in the docs, however it might be easier to simply create an entity and form type, with validation annotations? http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#validating-values-and-arrays

Answer (score 1):

The reason is the sendmail function in your server is not correct.

You can test with command: telnet localhost 25

If you are using Linux server. You should install Postfix, because SSMTP does not support telnet, while SwitfMailer always check telnet before sending email.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a bug with 2.3.3. Here's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/8700) discussing the matter.

The solution here appears to be to change your swiftmailer-bundle dependency in `composer.json` from 2.3.3 to 2.3.2:

```
"symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.2"
```

Comment: ok downgraded swiftMailer to 2.3.2 version like it's recommanded. So now, i have the error: Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message "".

Comment: ok with transport: mail in config_dev.yml, no error. But no received mail in my mailbox :s

Comment: I found this errors in apache logs: "sendmail: option requires an argument -- 'f'
sendmail: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory"