# Symfony2 send email not working

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

in config.yml

```
# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport:  sendmail
    username:  %mailer_user%
    password:  %mailer_password%   
    disable_delivery: false
```

in my controller:

```
$from = $data['email'];
//$sento = self::getSiteInfo()->getEmail();
$sento = 'devyoussef@gmail.com';                            
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance()
    ->setSubject('Nouveau message')
    ->setFrom($from)
    ->setTo($sento)
    ->setBody(
        $this->renderView(
            'RootSiteBundle:Front:email.txt.twig',
            array('data' =>$data)
        )
    );
$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

Comment: Please can you add more details regarding error messages / is the email making it to the mail queue?

Comment: there is no error message!, but the email not sent

Comment: Also what version of `swiftmailer` are you using? There was a bug with `sendmail` in `<v.2.3.2`. See this [question for details](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19911648/symfony2-swiftmailer-sendmail-transport-error).

Comment: Have you checked symfony logs / web server logs and mail server logs?

Comment: i'm using this version "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3", i have no hand at mail server logs, there is nothing particular in web server logs

Comment: Maybe mail is in spam? Check it.

Comment: that's true repincln, it goes to spam but that's after using v2.3.2, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to use : "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.2"

and check if the emails hasn't gone to spams folder.